# How to display an Integer Value in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c

One of My First View Controller's method returns an integer value which I want to display it in second view controllers's text field. how to set the value.because `UITetxtfield` takes only String as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the integer in a `NSString` using the method:

```
+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format
```

for example

```
int number = 0;

NSString *myString;

myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
```

Now number is saved in a `NSString` and you can use it on the `UITextField` property

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringWithFormat` to turn any variable to string type. This scenario will convert an integer type variable to string type:

```
Syntax: stringVariable=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"formatString",variable];

int i=12;
NSString *str;
str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
```